# delete duplicate records from master table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 mySQL tables (table Master and table Backup) Some rows are copied to backup table and some not...

Now I need to delete those all rows from Master Table which are availble in Backup table with single query, coz approx. 700k+ rows are in both tables

Comment: Use something like: delete from master where id in (select id from backup table)

Comment: I have to ask, why do you need to do this in a single query?  Seems like doing a `DELETE` with a `LIMIT` to delete the rows in smaller chunks would be much easier on your transaction log...

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM master_table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM backup_table)
```

Of course it needs unique key on id field to work

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this:

```
DELETE m
FROM master_table m
JOIN backup_table b ON b.id = m.id
```

Using an `IN` clause for that many rows is bound to have performance issues.